# Error with GRUB installation

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, grub

I have the follow error when I try to install grub on my system:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot     Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be         installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists     are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

I have searched on google and I have found that it is a space problem but I don't understand it because I have enough space between partitions. These are my partitions tables:

For my primary disk:

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1      30720    206847    176128    86M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2     206848    468991    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     468992 167772159 167303168  79.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  167792640 177772543   9979904   4.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  177793024 185792511   7999488   3.8G Linux swap
/dev/sda7  185812992 488378367 302565376 144.3G Linux filesystem
```

For my secondary disk:

```
Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            2048  904949759  904947712 431.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       904970238 1953523711 1048553474   500G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       904970240 1953523711 1048553472   500G 83 Linux
```

My primary disk is a SSD disk and my secondary disk is a HDD disk. I want to use the SSD disk for the OS's (Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.10) and the secondary disk for save data.

In Ubuntu I have the follow partitions:

```
/dev/sda4 --> /boot
/dev/sda6 --> swap
/dev/sda7 --> /
/dev/sdb5 --> /home
```

In the SSD disk I have 10MB of unallocated space at the begining of disk, beetween partitions and at the end of disk.

Why can I solve the this error? Maybe adding more unallocated space between partitions? Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can run gdisk on the disk, create the BIOS boot partition, and finally run grub again. Going by memory alone, I think you could try the following steps (please check the man page for gdisk as I cannot guarantee against loss of data!!).

```
sudo gdisk /dev/sdX
# type x for expert menu
# type l to set the sector alignment value
# set it to 1
# type m to go back to main menu
# type n to create a new partition
# choose a partition number (e.g. 128)
# first sector: 34
# last sector: 2047
# Hex code or GUID: ef02 (BIOS boot partition)
# type w to write your partition table and exit
```

Comment: Thank you Luca, you are right, I forgot to create the BIOS boot partition...